# Proper indentation in acronym package

Tags: indentation, acronyms

I am using the acronym package in the thesis. This is the first time I am using this so don't know much. But I did something like this.

```
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{2G}{2nd Generation}
  \acro{3GPP}{3rd Generation Partnership Project}
\end{acronym}
```

This is ok and gives me the acronym list but I find that the output is not properly indented.

so its like

```
2G 2nd Generation
3GPP 3rd Generation Partnership Project
```

I want the abbreviations and full forms properly indented so that it looks better. So something like.

```
2G         2nd Generation
3GPP       3rd Generation Partnership Project
```

How do I do this?

**EDIT: Also, I find that the list is not sorted. How do I get the acronym list sorted by alphabets.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As for your second question, I am not aware of a solution using `acronym` but it can be done using [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/). The package you are using at the moment is as far as I can tell nothing more than a tool for an appropriate layout, `glossaries` can do (much more).

Comment: I unhesitatingly second this advice. If there were any way to do it, do yourself a favour and switch to the `glossaries` package right now. You won't be sorry; it's the best package out there since sliced packaged bread (except for `microtype`, that is). `:)`

Answer (score 15):

Put the longest acronym in brackets after `\begin{acronym}`:

```
\begin{acronym}[3GPP]
```

(Learned from the [acronym documentation](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf).)

Comment: This works but it messes my fonts.

Comment: See [Parameter to the acronym environment changes the font of the acronym column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61556).

Comment: works kinda. It doesn't align the second line properly, if the description of the acronym requires one.