# Parameter to the acronym environment changes the font of the acronym column

Tags: fonts, acronyms

If I add a parameter to the `acronym` environment in order to set the width of the acronym column, the font of the text in the acronym column automatically changes. How can I prevent (or at least control) that? Below is a MWE with a parameter `[PdL]` loaded:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}[PdL]
    \acro{PD}{Democratic Party (\textit{Partito Democratico})}
    \acro{PdL}{The People of Freedom (\textit{Il Popolo della Libertà})}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image: Parameter loaded]

And below is the output of the same example, but without the parameter `[PdL]` loaded:

[image: No parameter loaded]

Comment: Wow, that's random! And I [didn't believe it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/proper-indentation-in-acronym-package/4836#comment101305_4836) ...

Comment: So, is it a bug?

Comment: I just did exactly the same fix as in the answer below before starting to post an almost identical question.  This seems to be an inexplicable decision to hard-code, especially as it's unique to the case of a defined width.  With my paranoid hat on I might be inclined to think it was designed to catch out those who leave such tidying until the deadline is looming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a precise choice by the package author. If no optional argument to `acronym` is specified, the list is typeset as a plain `description` environment. Otherwise the optional argument sets the label width and `\bflabel` is used to typeset the acronym.

Of course `\bflabel` can be redefined in the preamble; the default definition is

```
\def\bflabel#1{{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}\hfill}}
```

However the implementation is not well done, as the width is set using

```
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}
```

anyway, instead of the correct

```
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\bflabel{#1}}
```

---

A "more correct" implementation that uses `\bflabel` also without an optional argument is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{acronym}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{AC@deflist}[1]%
  {\ifAC@nolist
   \else
     \raggedright
   \begin{list}{}{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\bflabel{#1}}%
                  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
                  \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
                  \let\makelabel\bflabel}%
   \fi}
  {\ifAC@nolist
   \else
     \end{list}%
   \fi}
\renewenvironment{acronym}[1][1]
  {%
   \providecommand*{\acro}{\AC@acro}%
   \providecommand*{\acroplural}{\AC@acroplural}%
   \long\def\acroextra##1{##1}%
   \def\@tempa{1}\def\@tempb{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
     \global\expandafter\let\csname ac@des@mark\endcsname\AC@used
     \ifAC@nolist
     \else
       \begin{description}\let\makelabel\bflabel
     \fi
   \else
     \begin{AC@deflist}{#1}%
   \fi
  }
  {%
   \ifx\AC@populated\AC@used
   \else
     \ifAC@nolist
      \else
        \item[]\relax%
     \fi
   \fi
   \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@des@mark\endcsname\AC@used
     \ifAC@nolist
     \else
       \end{description}%
      \fi
   \else
      \end{AC@deflist}%
   \fi}
\makeatother

% Provide here a new definition for \bflabel if desired
%\def\bflabel#1{{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}\hfill}}


\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}[PdL]
    \acro{PD}{Democratic Party (\textit{Partito Democratico})}
    \acro{PdL}{The People of Freedom (\textit{Il Popolo della Libert√†})}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Weird choice by the package author (I think), but great explanation!